# web scraping for counting news about stocks

Tags: web-scraping

for an assignment I have I need to count the number of news on different stocks and compare it by graph, this is the link to the site and I attached an example for one of the stock where you can see 49 times for this specific stock,
what will be the best way to attack it -using what type of  package-bs4 or another one  ? what is the best approach here ?
url='https://www.calcalist.co.il/stocks/home/0,7340,L-3959-1102532--4,00.html'
[image]

Comment: All you want to get is that number? I.e. 49 in case of your example.

Comment: Yes but the 49 is an example, I will need it for additional ten other stocks so there should be few numbers